# jQuery load() issue with IE7 and 8

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive been searching hours to find the best solution for the jquery .load issue which effects ie7 and 8, I have the following block of code which is loading my content from a external jsp page with no problem on all the browsers except the ever bugger IE7 and 8.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#myDiv').load('test.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 10000); 
});
```

I have found many workaround like setting new Date like:

```
$('#myDiv').load('test.jsp',{noncache: new Date().getTime()},function(){..}).fadeIn("slow");
```

But did not work for me and still the content does not get loaded on IE7 and 8.

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings showing up in the developer console?

Comment: no, no error on consol

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you want the content to fadeIn, then it has to initially be hidden.  It can't fadeIn if the containing div is already visible.

Secondly, there are versions of IE that are a bit zealous with caching and you can defeat the caching with an unique argument in the URL (like you tried).

Thirdly, `.load()` isn't an animation so it doesn't use the animation queue so if you want to do something after the load completes, then you need to do it in the completion function.  You have pieces of these last two but haven't put them all together.

You could combine all three of these with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myDiv = $('#myDiv');
    setInterval(function () {
        myDiv.fadeOut('slow', function() {
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            myDiv.load('test.jsp?unique=' + now, function() {
                myDiv.fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    }, 10000); 
});
```

Comment: when I set the new date, nothing gets loaded, even on browsers on which the pages was loaded fine previously!

Comment: @ComeRun - then perhaps you need to check your server and see what it returns when there's a query parameter in the URL.  It could be the server is rejecting any URL with a query parameter (which would be an unusual practice).  Try just putting `http://yourdomain.com/test.jsp?unique=3333` into the browser and see what displays.  Does that return anything?  You could also probably fix this issue on the server by having the server return the right header fields that instruct the browser NOT to cache that page.